# Formula to condtionally sum an array of values from one sheet to give totals on another

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have two sheets, connected by ID, which contain details of events and charges.

Sheet1 (breakdown of charges):
[Oh, just discovered I'm not allowed to include screen shots. I apparently need 10 reputation points.  Not sure how to show you my spreadsheet now...]

```
ID   DBF    PCC    Extras
 1                 200
 1         100  
 3   200
 4   350        
 4         250  
 4               75
 4               25
 7   100
```

[Sorry this will probably look horrible, I can't figure out how to include a spreadseet snippet without using an image. I had 3 imaage all prepared ready.]

Sheet2 (indentification and summary information):

```
ID  Type    Name
3   MON Edwards
7   REC Smith
4   WDG Jones
1   FNL West
8   WDG Richards
9   WDG Morrison
11  INT Gray
```

I am trying to add three additional columns to sheet 2 so that it shows a summary of the charges for each event.  I would the charges information to update automatically in sheet2 as detail is added to sheet 1.

The resulting sheet2 will look like this:

```
ID  Type    Name    DBF PCC Extras
3   MON Edwards 200     
7   REC Smith   100     
4   WDG Jones   350 250 100
1   FNL West        100 200
8   WDG Richards            
9   WDG Morrison            
11  INT Gray
```

As data for ID 8, 9 and 11 is added to sheet1, the summations should automatically appear in sheet2.

I have been trying to create an array formula to put in sheet2:B2, something like this:

```
 =QUERY('Log Items'!A:F, "select sum(C), sum(D), sum(E), sum(F) where A="&A:A, 0)
```

This produces the correct result for ID 1 but it stops there and I'm not sure why.  Also, despite my 0 as the third parameter, the header row is output.

I tried encapsulating the above in an ARRAYFORMULA but get a parse error.

I have also tried various combinations of ARRAYFORMULA, SUM and IF but not got anything that works. For example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF('Log Items'!A:A=A:A,'Log Items'!C:E,0)))
```

This gives #N/A "argument out of range", which I don't understand.

Although I've been working with Excel for a while, I'm really new to Google's Array formulas but have mananged to use them successfully in other parts of my spreadsheet and found them really powerful.

If anyone could help me with this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Upload the screenshots [somewhere](http://imgur.com/) and link to them (preferably with a direct link to the image). Someone who comes along might upload them to [so] for you. Although text does have certain advantages. Also, please include a tag for the tool you're using ([tag:google-spreadsheet]?).

Comment: I don't seem to have permission to edit my post or to change flags.  Only the "share" and "delete" options are active.  Anyway, I have put the screen shots on Photo Bucket:
http://s1283.photobucket.com/user/chris21-7/media/My%20Public%20Images/FeesDB_pic1_zps02c44837.png.html
http://s1283.photobucket.com/user/chris21-7/media/My%20Public%20Images/FeesDB_pic2_zps4113e02e.png.html
http://s1283.photobucket.com/user/chris21-7/media/My%20Public%20Images/FeesDB_pic3_zps17583718.png.html

Comment: Yes, I should have checked the google-spreadsheet tag.  Sorry, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sheet2!D2:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A,MMULT(N(A2:A=TRANSPOSE('Log Items'!A2:A)),N('Log Items'!B2:D)),))`

Note: the N() functions have become necessary with different coercion behaviour in the new version of Sheets. They can be omitted in the classic version.

[MMULT usage](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZdNQHjqWKqdDFYUGl5TG9lYzczd1FHQVFBUmZ2aHc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Wow!  That works absolutely perfectly.  Thank you so much. I don't think I would have ever figured that one out, but the description in the link you provided makes it really clear.